# Rvalue reference constructor incorrectly called with an lvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

When I compile this code:

```
class Base { /*...*/ };
class Derived : public Base { /*...*/ };

class C
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    C(T const& inBase) : baseInC(new T(inBase)) { /*...*/ }

    template<typename T>
    C(T&& inBase) : baseInC(new T(std::move(inBase))) { /*...*/ }

    std::unique_ptr<Base> baseInC;
};

int main()
{
    Base base;
    Derived derived;

    C ca(base);
    C cb(derived);

    C cc( (Base()) );
    C cd( (Derived()) );

    return 0;
}
```

I get a the compiler message:

`In instantiation of C::C(T&&) [with T = Base&]': required from C ca(base); error: new cannot be applied to a reference type`

`In instantiation of C::C(T&&) [with T = Derived&]': required from C cb(derived); error: new cannot be applied to a reference type`

It looks like `C ca(base);` is being associated with the rvalue reference ctor call. Why is the compiler having difficulty associating this line with the first ctor? The construction of `cc` and `cd` works as expected if I comment out the offending lines.

Comment: Read up on universal references.

Comment: [The Universal Reference/Overloading Collision Conundrum—Scott Meyers](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/07/the-universal-reference-overloading-collision-conundrum-scott-meyers).

Comment: In written form here http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're going to copy *or* move anyway, pass by value. In a simplified way:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
    T * p = new T(std::move(x));
}
```

Otherwise, if you have a universal reference like `template <typename T> ... T &&`, you can get the base type as `typename std::decay<T>::type` (from `<type_traits>`). In that case, you should pass the argument as `std::forward<T>(inBase)`.

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to work for the temporaries, though. If I put a print statement in the ctor, nothing is printed in the lines `C cc( (Base()) );` and `C cd( (Derived()) );`.

Comment: Ah nevermind. It was the MVP problem. I put the extra parentheses in in my question, but not in my actual code. Oops. @Sebastian Redi: Why is that a good thing? I want the code to make a copy of the temps locally. Isn't that a pretty safe thing to do?

Comment: @Fadecomic Whenever the compiler elides a copy, that's a good thing. It will never do it when it's unsafe. In general, when a temp is elided, it's because the object is constructed directly in its final location.

Answer (score 0):

overloading on universal reference is a bad idea( see Scott Meyer's recent talk ).

```
C ca(base);
C cb(derived);
```

these will call the templated universal reference constructor because universal reference binds to ***everything***, and since `base` and `derived` is not passed in as a `const &`, it will not bind to the first constructor. Instead the compiler deduced the template argument to be `Base & &&` and `Derived & &&` and after reference collapsing rule you get `Base &` and `Derived &` which ultimately invoke the error.

```
C cc( (Base()) );
C cd( (Derived()) );
```

these work because temporary can only bind to `const &` thus the first constructor is a better match.